# twig: create custom tag that calls a functions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

**SETUP:**

- Twig 1.13.1
- PHP 5.4.3

---

**PROBLEM:**

I am needing help setting up a custom tag that calls a function that i have already built...

---

**Current Code:**

Template Code

```
{% set stories = get_latest_stories(2, sports) %}

{% for story in stories %}
    {{ story.headline }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Controller

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('getViewStories', function (section, limit) {
    return news_stories::getStories(section,limit);
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
$twig->render("storyList.html");
```

---

**GOAL:**

No with that said I would like to use a custom tag like

```
{% get_latest_stories 2 sports %}
```

to call the same function as above. The new way looks nicer and is easier to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not fetch your stories in the controller instead of the template? This does not seem like a job for the view layer...

So, something like this:

```
$twig->render("storyList.html", array(
    'stories' => news_stories::getStories($section, $limit)
));
```

Then, you'll have a `stories` variable available in your template.

Comment: where do i set the section and limit for "getStories($section, $limit)"

Comment: I don't know your application, so I can't tell you that. Where do you get them from when you're calling the function in the template?

Answer (score 1):

here is simple example how to write twig extension
Following code is taken from my unfinished project

```
function file_import($value){
    //some code here
    return $value;
}
$app['twig']->addFunction('file_import', new Twig_Function_Function('file_import'));
```

usage

```
{{ file_import('value') }}
```

Comment: We are using django templates which is much like twig in their template tags. To handle the transfer over to php we would like to keep most of the template tags as is and write code around them so that we can almost move all the template over with out changing them.